Save progress - Bypass required fields
I have a form that contains different types of inputs including several radio buttons with the required attribute. I am attempting to add a 'Save progress' link that when clicked, will override the required attributes (by selecting a choice) and submit the form. To make this work, I added another choice (N/A) to all of the radio buttons. That choice is made non-visible with the help of jquery. When that submit link is clicked, it's supposed to select all radio buttons that don't have a selection and set them to the 'N/A' choice, then submit the form. Upon returning to the form (on page load), all radio buttons with 'N/A' selected, are made unselected.
At least this is the way it's supposed to work. What's actually happening, is all radio buttons end up being unselected. Even the ones that had choices other than 'N/A' selected.
Below is the code I'm currently using:
// On page load, hide the 'N/A' choice for all radio buttons
$('input[type=radio][value="N/A"]').hide().parent().hide();

// On page load, uncheck/unset all radio buttons that have 'N/A' selected
$('input[type=radio][value="N/A"]').each(function() {
    //var selectedValue = $('input[name="survey"]:checked').val();
    //$(this).val("");
    $(this).prop("checked",false);
     
});

// When 'quick save' button is clicked, set value of all unslected radio buttons to 'N/A' (to override required attribute) and submit.
$(document).on('click', '.qksv', function() {   
    $('input[type=radio]:not(:checked)').each(function() {
        //if(this.checked == false) {
            $(this).val("N/A");
                $(this).prop('checked',true);
                //$(this).attr("required", false);              
        //}
    });
    $(this).submit();       
});

HTML:
Below is one of the radio groups. There are nine of them in this form and they contain the same data. Only the names are different. They are named: radio_1, radio_2, radio_3, etc...
<div class="col-12">
    <div class="form-group required-control">
        <label class=" form-label fw-bold" for="radio_1">Next activity?</label>
        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
            <input type="radio" name="radio_1" id="radio_1_0" class="form-check-input" value="Another ticket" data-alias="" data-required="true">
            <label for="radio_1_0" class="form-check-label">
                Another ticket
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
            <input type="radio" name="radio_1" id="radio_1_1" class="form-check-input" value="Travel home" data-alias="" data-required="true">
            <label for="radio_1_1" class="form-check-label">
                Travel home
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check form-check-inline" style="display: none;">
            <input type="radio" name="radio_1" id="radio_1_2" class="form-check-input" value="N/A" data-alias="" data-required="true" style="display: none;">
            <label for="radio_1_2" class="form-check-label">
                N/A
            </label>
        </div>
        <span id="radio_1"></span>
        
    </div>
</div>

What am I doing wrong? I get the same results even when I comment out those two sections of code that are triggered on page load.
I don't have control over the HTML so it cannot be changed.
I don't have control over the HTML. It is generated. The form has multiple steps (pages) with 'Next' and 'Previous' buttons. I've tried adding code to the 'Save Progress' link to remove the required attributes before submit but I could not get that to work either. Those radio fields are required because when any one of the radio groups has "Travel home" selected, several proceeding form fields are hidden and the user is taken to the last step of the form. Setting a default value/option for all of the radio buttons would defeat the purpose of having steps. The form will be accessed multiple times throughout the day. Users can edit their submissions because the server populates the fields with the previously saved data. More data will be added each time it is accessed. The final step is a review and submission. The 'Save Progress' link is useful because it will submit the current data, allow empty fields and skip the review step. This will save a lot of time and make the form easier to use.

Please include the relevant html so we can have a full picture of the problem.

If the goal is to allow the form to be posted without requiring all fields then why not simply remove the required attributes?  This seems like an awkward workaround otherwise.

The "Save Progress" button shouldn't be a submit button, then the browser won't check for all required fields being filled in.

"Upon returning to the form (on page load), all radio buttons with 'N/A' selected, are made unselected." Yeah of course, you never applied that saved information to the radio buttons after the page reloaded. The default behavior of a form after submitting is to reset the page. In order to keep the radio buttons selected add event.preventDefault() or have the server restore the page.

Unless I'm missing something, if you control the server then just treat the saved info as a normal submit but add a hidden input that adds a value of incomplete: true.

I added context to the OP to answer these comments.

I don't know the context for your logic but seems like N/A option is basically the default option?
<div class="question">
  <p>Question 1</p>
  <label><input type="radio" name="q1" value="Yes"> Yes</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="q1" value="No"> No</label>
  <input type="radio" name="q1" value="N/A" checked hidden> <- just make it default and hidden?
</div>

If you still want to proceed tho.. I think this part of the code is not doing what you expect:
// this will just select all radio inputs that are not checked
// ignoring the ones that are actually checked...
$('input[type=radio]:not(:checked)').each(function() {
  //if(this.checked == false) {
    $(this).val("N/A"); // careful, this will potentially override the values of all your inputs!
    $(this).prop('checked',true); // here you're just checking all of them?
    //$(this).attr("required", false);              
  //}
});

If I understand, I think what you might actually want is something like this:
// [on quick save function]

// 1. group your radio inputs by name:
const groups = new Set(
  $("input:radio")
    .get()
    .map((el) => el.name)
);

// 2. now, for each radio group...
groups.forEach((name) => {
  const group = $(`input:radio[name=${name}]`);
  // if a given group doesn't have a selection...
  if (!group.is(":checked")) {
    // check the N/A option for this group before submit
    group.filter('[value="N/A"]').prop("checked", true);
  }
});
...


The N/A option is not the default option. No option is set to default. During a submission, users have to make a choice before they can continue to the next form step. I'm trying to bypass this requirement for when the Save Progress link is used.

Ok, did you have a chance to try with the code above?

Thank you so very much! It took me a little while to understand your awesome code. It works beautifully. I now understand why my code was not working as expected.
